# How to access Images from Saved Images programaically in iphone WITHOUT UImagePickerController?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I know how to let user select an image from UIImagePickerController, but I don't want that.
I just want to have NSArray of images stored in the phone, but I don't want to involve user (to select a one and then have that image...),rather, I have created my own custom Image selector controller and want to have source as the gallary.

Comment: check this [link](https://github.com/jeena/JPImagePickerController)

Comment: Using Assets you get the photos http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/01_UsingAssets.html

Comment: @MuditBajpai: This didn't work for me...I want Array of images those are stored in phone...I don't want to specify any external images to be shown in the View, rather, I want to have images of the phone gallery itself....Hope you understand..

Comment: Users certainly would not want to let you access their entire photo album, and keep a record of photos taken separately. It's not as bad as copying the Address Book or Contacts, but still is a gray area. Why do you need so many and not just one?

Comment: I used ELCImagePickerController: http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/03/03/update-elcimagepickercontroller/

Comment: @MishieMoo: I want to let user select multiple images at a time, I have created a customized TableView for that, which lets user to select multiple Photos at a time and also to modify some photos as per his wish and upload selected images to some social networking site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can easily do that using the AVFoundation and AssetsLibrary framework. Here is the code to access all the photos:

```
-(void)addPhoto:(ALAssetRepresentation *)asset
{
    //NSLog(@"Adding photo!");
    [photos addObject:asset];
}

-(void)loadPhotos
{
    photos = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];    
    library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];    

    // Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
    if([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) 
        {        
             // Within the group enumeration block, filter if necessary
             [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];           
             [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop)
              {                                 
                  // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.            
                  if (alAsset)
                  {
                      ALAssetRepresentation *representation = [alAsset defaultRepresentation];                      
                      [self addPhoto:representation];                      
                  }       
                  else
                  {
                      NSLog(@"Done! Count = %d", photos.count);
                      //Do something awesome
                  }
              }];
         }
         failureBlock: ^(NSError *error) {
         // Typically you should handle an error more gracefully than this.
         NSLog(@"No groups");                                 
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Great...Thank You Very Much Dude...I did similar, except I allowed user to select whether he wants images from Saved Photos, Albums or any other source (in TableView)..and as per that selection, I put Images to my customized Gallery.

Comment: Nice, that's even better. For future viewers of this post, could you accept this answer as the correct answer?