# Check Photo gallery is accessible or not iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

I am accessing the photo gallery using below code :

```
UIImagePickerController* picker = [UIImagePickerController new];
picker.sourceType = type;
picker.mediaTypes =
    [UIImagePickerController availableMediaTypesForSourceType:type];
picker.delegate = self;
[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So I user open Gallery for first time then application is display popup like this :

[image]

If user select the OK then its work fine. But if user select the Don't Allow then photo gallery is not able to access from application. My question is **if user open Photo Gallery then how to check whether photo gallery is accessible or not.**

If user is not allow then application is display the screen like this :

[image]

But is there any way to check Accessibility before opening the window. 
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check your access ability using `ALAuthorizationStatusAuthorized`.

Check authorization status of the app.

```
  ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {

//THen code here ,,,,

    }
```

Comment: If user don't allow then application is automatically display the picker and say app is not allow the photo gallery. Should we check it before opening it? Please check the new image which i upload on question.

Comment: Above if condition will check whether per mission is available or not ...then in if condition you can code for opening UIImagePicker ,,,

Answer (score 0):

you might looking for [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9805562/2695503) in failure block you can show alert to user that then can give access by go to settings....

Comment: With this solution, we get photo directly but we are not to check the accessibility.