# How to load photoalbums from device to an app witout UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios

I want to write an app which load photo albums from devise gallery like UIImagePickerController doe's it.

I've look around some posts and found nice sample how to do this:
[How to access Images from Saved Images programaically in iphone WITHOUT UImagePickerController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9736864/how-to-access-images-from-saved-images-programaically-in-iphone-without-uimagepi)

but the problem is that this method load all the photos from device without dividing them for albums. So I would be very pleased if some one help me to manage this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is controlled by which groups you choose to enumerate. So, you can limit your enumeration to `ALAssetsGroupAlbum`. You can get the album name by requesting `valueForProperty: ALAssetsGroupPropertyName` on the groups returned.

Comment: so, and what - (id)valueForProperty:(NSString *)property method returns? I watched and fond out that it returns "The group’s value for property", but what kind of format is it?

Comment: When you request the name it will return a string. The return type depends on the property you request.